# How to close a pyglet screen after 2 seconds in python

Tags: python, pygame, pyglet

I am making a project in which a video has to be played. I want that when the video is finished the pyglet window closes and imports the ninja game window.

Here is my code:

```
import pyglet

vidPath = 'intro.mp4'
window= pyglet.window.Window(1000,780)
player = pyglet.media.Player()
source = pyglet.media.StreamingSource()
MediaLoad = pyglet.media.load(vidPath)

player.queue(MediaLoad)
player.play()


@window.event
def on_draw():
    if player.source and player.source.video_format:
        player.get_texture().blit(0,0)



pyglet.app.run()

import Ninja_Game
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def close_pyglet(dt):
    pyglet.app.exit()

    import Ninja_Game

pyglet.clock.schedule_once(close_pyglet, 2)
```